# CloudWatch only capturing last metric produced by SageMaker training job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Amazon SageMaker to train a PyTorch model and attempting to visualise the loss values in CloudWatch. I create my estimator:

```py
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch

estimator = PyTorch(
    entry_point="train.py",
    source_dir=source_dir,
    role=role,
    framework_version=framework_version,
    py_version="py3",
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type=instance_type,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    metric_definitions=[
        {"Name": "train:loss", "Regex": "Train Loss:([0-9\\.]+)"},
        {"Name": "val:loss", "Regex": "Val Loss:([0-9\\.]+)"},
    ],
    enable_sagemaker_metrics=True
)
```

and execute the training job:

```py
estimator.fit(s3_url)
```

Which runs successfully, but when I look at the algorithm metrics in CloudWatch for the training job this creates, it seems to only capture the last reported loss values. This is also the case when using the TrainingJobAnalytics:

```py
from sagemaker.analytics import TrainingJobAnalytics

analysis = TrainingJobAnalytics(training_job_name=estimator._current_job_name)
df = analysis.dataframe()
df
```

where the output looks like:

```
    timestamp   metric_name value
0         0.0   train:loss  0.471061
1         0.0   val:loss    0.167700
```

In the CloudWatch logs there are multiple values being logged but they do not appear to be captured. I was wondering whether someone could provide some advice for how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post cloudwatch logs ?

Comment: @rok Here is a snippet, I have to divide it into two comments sorry:

`2021-07-20T16:27:04.407+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Train Loss:0.699654
2021-07-20T16:27:04.407+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Val Loss:0.5292
2021-07-20T16:27:04.407+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:--- Starting epoch 1 ---
2021-07-20T16:27:04.407+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Train Loss:0.624594
2021-07-20T16:27:04.407+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Val Loss:0.4473
2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:--- Starting epoch 2 ---
2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Train Loss:0.556522
2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Val Loss:0.3371`

Comment: @rok Second snippet:

`2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:--- Starting epoch 3 ---

2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Train Loss:0.492183

2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Val Loss:0.2584

2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:--- Starting epoch 4 ---

2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Train Loss:0.471061

2021-07-20T16:27:04.408+10:00 DEBUG:__main__:Val Loss:0.1677

2021-07-20T16:27:04.409+10:00 2021-07-20 06:27:03,618 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO Reporting training SUCCESS`

Comment: is this the whole traning job ? I suspect that everything is too fast for cloudwatch.. If I remember well metrics are reported with 1 minute frequency.. so try to train longer to see if this is the problem..

Comment: @rok I had a similar problem where training jobs metrics disappeared. Your solution worked well. Putting a time.sleep(60) at the end of the training code solved it.